# How to "reset" Sharepoint 2010 installation

Tags: 2010, installation, windows-server-2008-r2

The SharePoint Development machine is a stand-alone machine that is not connected to a network. It is mainly used for the development of web parts and such. I am a well rounded .NET Developer who is temporarily filling the SharePoint Development role. While learning SharePoint, I created a new Site Collection and was following along with a tutorial in a book. I'm not sure how or what happened, but I seem to have caused an not so easily recoverable issue. At this point, it has been advised that I simply re-install SharePoint on the machine. How do I do this in a way that will allow me to not lose my content (site collections, web parts, custom lists, etc?) I have googled this topic so many times in so many ways it is making me sick. I understand that SharePoint can be extremely difficult to fix due to the many things that could go wrong, but I have yet to find a straight-forward answer as to how to go about this process. Do to the issue, I do not have access to Central Admin and SharePoint Powershell.

Edit:
I might be on to something. I am getting to following Error in the EventViewer:

```
  Load control template file /_controltemplates/TaxonomyPicker.ascx failed: Could not load type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.WebControls.TaxonomyPicker' from assembly
  'Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c'.
```

and the following warning:

```
    Volume Shadow Copy Service error: Failed resolving account spFarmAcc with status 1376. Check connection to domain controller and VssAccessControl registry key.
    Error-specific details: Error: NetLocalGroupGetMembers(spFarmAcc), 0x80070560, The specified group does not exist.
```

Comment: Could you explain what you did to break it?  There may be an easier route than reinstalling.  Simply creating a new Site Collection shouldn't cause any issues.

Comment: That's the problem, being that I'm new to all of this I don't know what I could have done to break it. Let me gather some exact log messages and will update the post.

Comment: According to http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2481844, the error about the TaxonomyPicker is to be treated as log noise and only occurs after an IIS Reset.

Comment: DaveWise, I have attempted to correct these errors with no luck. Are you able to guide me in reinstalling SharePoint?

Comment: These errors should have no impact on SharePoint in general and should not be related to any reason that you cannot access sites.  What error, specifically, are you getting when trying to access a site?  Did you change Alternate Access Mappings or the Bindings in IIS?  I'll see what I can put together on the reinstall...

Comment: Dave, everything suddenly automagically works again. This whole situation is so mind-boggling, and it's honestly putting a bad taste in my mouth concerning SharePoint. Currently, I am running a full farm content and configuration backup just in case I run into issues again, which I am almost sure that I will. Don't feel rushed, but instructions on performing a reinstall and restoration would still be useful and would answer my original question.

Comment: Should it come up again, please make note of the last few things you did to the environment before it went bonkers.  However, as long as you deploy your changes via approved methods (i.e. as a WSP rather than piecemeal or xcopy) then you probably will not have problems.